# Timeout not working in CGI script

Tags: apache, cgi

I have the following CGI script (Apache 2.4 on Linux)

`#!/bin/sh
timeout 1 sleep 10`

As the script above does not produce any output, an error will eventually be reported. Apparently, the script is not working as expected, as the error is delivered after ~10 seconds rather than 1.

Why isn't `timeout` doing what it's supposed to do here? How can I fix it?

Comment: However, this works: `timeout -s9 1 sleep 10` I suspect that Apache traps SIGTERM.

Comment: httpd does have a customs signal handler for SIGTERM, but apache forks+execs the CGI script so it should be reset.